# What should UnityContainer.Teardown method do?

Tags: .net, unity-container

I would like to explicitly "release" object instance resolved by Unity. I hoped the Teardown method should be used exactly for this so I tried something like this:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IMyType), typeof(MyType), 
    new MyLifetimeManager());
var obj = container.Resolve<IMyType>();
...
container.Teardown(obj);
```

`MyLifetimeManager` stores object instance in `HttpContext.Current.Items`. I expected that `Teardown` method will call `RemoveValue` on lifetime manager and release both MyType instance and lifetime manager instance. It doesn't work. First of all `RemoveValue` is not called and if I again call `Resolve<IMyType>` I will get previously resolved instance.

What should `Teardown` method do? How can I release object despite of his lifetime manager?

**Edit:**

If `Teardown` doesn't release the instance, who does? Who calls `RemoveValue` on lifetime manager?

Comment: looking at the vague "cleans it up" comment on MSDN, I'm assuming TearDown returns a pristine object, as if it were newly created.

Comment: (Although looking through the Unity source, can't see many implementations of Teardown doing anything at all... But no time to check them all.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity TearDown doesn't do anything out of the box. You do not need to remove from HttpContext.Current.Items as it will be cleared automatically at the end of the request. What you may want to do is call Dispose on any IDisposable object stored there. You would do this from EndRequest in Global.asax:

```
foreach (var item in HttpContext.Current.Items.Values)
            {
                var disposableItem = item as IDisposable;

                if (disposableItem != null)
                {
                    disposableItem.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Actually I want to remove it from HttpContext because after this special method I need Unity to create new instance.

Comment: You want to remove the item(s) from the HttpContext and repopulate by calling container.Resolve all within the same request?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want. I have special method which is called only occasionaly (session start) but it is still part of actual http request. I need this method to call container.Resolve and get "temporary" instance which is released so that rest of the request gets its own instance. The reason is that I'm using ParameterOverrides to pass some arguments into dependency hiearchy and these arguments are different in initialization method. I don't want rest of the request to work with instance initialized with these arguments.

Comment: Don't use a lifetime manager at all. Thus every time you call Resolve a fresh instance is created. And this instance can be disposed via it's own dispose implementation.